# Flutter Camera - Video recording pause resume not working properly

Tags: flutter, android-camera, flutter-dependencies, android-camera2, video-recording

I'm developing a feature where if the user starts video recording and puts the app in the background then the recording should be paused and when the user comes back to the app it should be resumed.
Now if I came back within 60 secs then it is working fine but after 60 secs I'm getting these logs -

open | onError
open | onClosed

and when I resume the app I get this exception -

E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera_android( 4852): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaRecorder.resume()' on a null object reference
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera_android( 4852): at io.flutter.plugins.camera.Camera.resumeVideoRecording(Camera.java:820)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera_android( 4852): at io.flutter.plugins.camera.MethodCallHandlerImpl.onMethodCall(MethodCallHandlerImpl.java:136)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera_android( 4852): at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera_android( 4852): at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera_android( 4852): at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:319)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera_android( 4852): at io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown Source:12)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera_android( 4852): at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera_android( 4852): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera_android( 4852): at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera_android( 4852): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera_android( 4852): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera_android( 4852): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera_android( 4852): at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/camera_android( 4852): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)